# Copy and paste not working in ubuntu in VirtualBox 6.1.2

Tags: virtualbox, 20.04, copy-and-paste

I have gone to *Settings* → *General* → *Advanced* → *Shared clipboard* and changed to *Bidirectional*. Also did the same for *Drag'n'Drop* and changed it to *Bidirectional* too.

However I am still **unable to copy and paste from my Windows 10 desktop to my VirtualBox 6.1.2** which runs on Ubuntu 20.04.

I basically want to be able to copy and paste from my Windows machine to my virtual Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108745/discussion-on-question-by-shailaja-gupta-kapoor-copy-and-paste-not-working-in-ub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK fixed also for me, but in another way:

Check for updates didnt show newer, hence I thought its the newest.

Installed VBox 6.1.8, replaced 6.0.22, clipboard works.

Answer (score 7):

I cannot comment but when I used Windows 8, VM 5 and Ubuntu 18, I also had issues, and had to apply fixes, like:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Have you run these?
Now I try with Win 10, VM 6, Ubuntu 20 like you, and nothing helps...

Comment: This was accepted, but still does not work for me (Win 10, VM 6, Ubuntu 20)...

Answer (score 3):

You could also SSH into your Ubuntu VM and right-click to paste into the console.